# Can the review of a tenure track application start before the reference letters arrive?

Tags: recommendation-letter, job-search, faculty-application, tenure-track

I was chatting with some friends and some claimed that a tenure track applicant can be reviewed and invited to campus before letters arrive. However, others claim that without the arrival of all 3-5 reference letters nothing will move forward. Can the application review start before the arrival of reference letters or is it similar to graduate students' applications, where the graduate school will not forward the application documents to the department before they are complete?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any general rule for universities...

Comment: If they did not request letters, then yes, otherwise maybe.

Comment: Is this question about a particular country?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At least in my department, yes, faculty candidates can be interviewed before their reference letters arrive, although an actual *job offer* requires all letters.  (In fact, this is relatively common for more senior applicants, who often want to keep their application confidential as long as possible.)  But that was a policy decision by the department, made with the explicit approval of higher administration.  Other departments and other universities can set their own hiring policies/procedures/requirements.

The overarching rule (according to my understanding of US equal-opportunity labor laws) is that the hiring process must be *consistent*; the same process must be followed for all applicants.  If you interview one applicant before all their letters arrive, you cannot then claim that you didn't interview a second applicant because you didn't have all their letters.

(I ran my department's faculty hiring committee for three years.)

Comment: I don't think US law typically requires you to be consistent, but nonetheless that's pretty universally the policy for large employers.  Being inconsistent can get you in trouble with the law if you're inconsistent in specific ways that may suggest that you're illegally discriminating or may cause problems with requirements to preferentially hire US residents.  But if you decided that you wanted to require letters for people born in odd years but not for people born in even years, that wouldn't be illegal (because parity of birthyear is not a protected class).

Comment: I would think this is pretty generally the case if not universal. Waiting until "all" materials are received before reviewing anything would be impossible, since some things will never arrive. And it is a poor use of faculty/staff time to force a wait until the deadline before starting. Initial weeding out of the obviously not qualified can happen early and probably does.

Comment: @Noah Snyder: *require letters for people born in odd years but not for people born in even years* I like your example! And not just because I was born in an even year . . .

Comment: It's an interesting weird example because you might think that the protection against age discrimination would apply, but actually you're allowed to discriminate based on age, you're just not to discriminate *against people over 40*.

Comment: I'm aware of someone who was hired with a missing letter. Presumably the committee called the letter writer to ask what the deal was, and the answer was positive.

Comment: At least a third of the promised letters in the last search I was on never arrived.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo and what happened next? Did you remove the applicants or make offers without the letters?

Comment: @ZachH - at the company I work at, letters are not needed. Instead the hiring manager calls the references directly and runs through a standard set of questions. One less thing to keep track of.

Comment: @NoahSnyder _But if you decided that you wanted to require letters for people born in odd years but not for people born in even years, that wouldn't be illegal_ — It _might_ not be illegal, but I'm quite sure my university's lawyers wouldn't allow it.  By the same logic, I could regally require letters only from people whose name rhymes with Boa Rider.

Comment: @JeffE "regally"? :)

Comment: @paulgarrett We are only human.

Comment: @JeffE ... I see what you did there. :)